# SharePoint Online Retention labels

Tags: sharepoint-online, retention, compliance-center

Is there any way to move files when the retention labels in the compliance center are triggered.

We would like to move all files older than x month to an archive site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, it's impossible to move files when the retention labels in the compliance center are triggered.

As a workaround, you could enable the retention in Information management policy settings in SharePoint library to move files:

[image]